# How do I use jQuery to return the class of each checked checkbox as they are checked?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery for the first time (my js knowledge is poor at best) and attempting to create a Section filter (hides/shows divs depending on class) that is based around checkbox options.

To start with I was wanting to retrieve the class of each checkbox that was checked so I have something like this (the div.text is just to test the output). Each checkbox class corresponds to the class of the div (all div's have multiple classes that match various checkboxes)

```
<ul>
    <li>Size</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="half" />&frac12;"</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="quart" />&frac34;"</li>
</ul>

<script>
    function Checked() {
        var n = $("input:checked").attr("class");
        $("div.text").text(n);
    }

    Checked();
    $(":checkbox").click(Checked);
</script>
```

This succesfully returns the first checked checkbox class, I toyed around with each() but don't quite understand how to implement it, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Ultimately I'm looking for each checked checkbox class to be in an array that I can then call upon to make the corresponding divs the only visible items, but I'm happy to take this a step at a time. I'm sure this is likely to be an easier way to achieve the desired result so am also open to suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Return `n`. But if you're hiding/showing as checkboxes are checked/unchecked, it'd be easiest to just do it in the checked handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function Checked() {
  var classes = [];
  $("input:checked").each(function(){
       classes.push($(this).attr('class'));
  });
  $("div.text").text(classes.join(','));
}
Checked();
$(":checkbox").click(Checked);
```

Inside the each loop `this` points to each of the checked checkbox element. Using `this` we get the class and then push it inside an array just to store all the classes and then display them using `join` method of the array.

Comment: Just tried it now and it works, just have to work out where to go from there. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function Checked() {
    return $("input:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("class");
    }).get();
}

function showDivs() {
    var foo = Checked();
    // hide/show divs based on the array returned from the above function
}

showDivs();
$(":checkbox").click(showDivs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response here, I am just doing some reading on using arrays regarding hide/show you have suggested before I try to implement

Comment: my divs all have contain the class "com" in common. I'm not 100% sure how I'm supposed to call the array but made the assumption that the var foo would be the returned data. I tried something like this $('p.com[class~=foo]') to see if it would match any of the terms. I'm thinking I may need to to check it against each value, but after some reading can't seem to find the appropriate method. Can you point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

You maybe need to consider the `.each()` function, as the jQuery collection may have more than one item within it:

```
var classString;
$("input:checked").each(function(){
    classString += $(this).attr("class") + " "
});

$("div.text").text(classString);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the checkbox to open/close visible items, you can use this pattern:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="half" />&frac12;"
<div class="T_half" style="display:none">...</div>
```

JS:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $("T_"+$(this).attr("class")).toggle()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.

```
<ul>
  <li>Size</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="half" />&frac12;"</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="quart" />&frac34;"</li>
</ul>

<p>Results</p>
<div id="output"><div>

<script>
function Checked() {
    var classes = [];

    // this will be a bit different maybe per the markup
    // though it uses the each function to loop through and
    // get the class of each check element in the selector
    $('ul li input:checked').each(function(index) {
        classes.push($(this).attr('class'));
    });

    // ... do something ...
    // for now just update the #output html with the classes array content
    $('#output').html(classes.join(', '));
}

Checked();

$(":checkbox").click(Checked);
</script>
```